# Can we infer that these two exponential random variables ($T_A,T_B)$ are independent? why?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

> There's two lamps in a room. 
> One from type $A$, and one from type $B$. 
> Let $T_A$ be the lifetime of lamp $A$ (in months), and $T_B$ the life time of lamp $B$ (in months). 
> PDF's of $T_A,T_B:$ 
> $f_{T_B}=3e^{-3t}, t\ge 0$. and otherwise $0$. 
> $f_{T_A}=e^{-t}, t\ge 0$ . otherwise $0$. 
> basically $T_A\sim exp(1),   T_B\sim exp(3)$

The question was: We lit the two lamps together at the start of the month, what is the expected value of the time from the start of the month until the last lamp burns? 

The solution did this: 
$X=max\{T_A,T_B\}$. 
And so $E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}P(X>x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}(1-P(max\{T_A,T_B\}\le x)=\int_0^{\infty}(1-P(T_A\le x,T_B\le x)dx$. 
And then they did this: 
$\int_0^{\infty}1-P(T_A\le x)P(T_B\le x)dx$. 

I know that this comes from $T_A,T_B$ being independent, but the question doesn't say so, is there anything I'm missing in this question that tells me they're independent? How would I check that? 

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not say independent so you may need to justify it as a reasonable assumption

Comment: Incidentally, assuming independence, I would have answered the question as $E[\min(T_A,T_B)] + P(T_A \le T_B)E[T_B - T_A \mid T_A \le T_B]+ P(T_A > T_B)E[T_A - T_B \mid T_A > T_B] $ which is    $\frac{1}{3+1} + \frac{3}{3+1}\times \frac11+ \frac{1}{3+1}\times \frac13 = \frac{13}{12}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks alot, so basically I cannot "see" that they're independent until I prove/disprove that they are, or is there anything that really tells you they're most likely independent in the question? and if I wanted to prove, I'm not sure how to approach that. About your solution, I don't quite understand how you reached it, I guess it has to do with the logic: we take the minimum, which means the first lamp burned, and then something which has to do with complete probability, but I couldn't quite grasp it. and again thanks for the help!

Comment: It does not say independence and you cannot prove it from the question, but typically you are expected to assume it.  My solution is in effect the expected time for the first to fail plus the expected additional time for the next to fail, using memorylessness and other properties of exponential distributions.  Your approach should reach the same answer if neither of us have made a mistake

Comment: @Henry Yes the result is the same, and thank you now your solution is more clear, and it is really a nice solution, much better than integrals atleast, so basically you do expected time for first lamp, and then if the first lamp was $A$, then the rest of the time is $T_B-T_A$, else $T_A-T_B$, and you used this knowledge with memorylessness property and that is the part I couldn't get my head on, how did you calculate $E(T_B-T_A | T_A \le T_B)$? I have some weakness applying the memorylessness property in every question I face.

Comment: If $A$ fails first, i.e. $T_A<T_B$, then the *additional time* for $T_B$  to fail (i.e. $T_B-T_A$) is still exponential with the same rate (because $B$ has an exponential distribution, i.e. no memory of what happened earlier than $T_A$). This means  $E[T_B - T_A \mid T_A \le T_B] =E[T_B]$

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much! just to make sure, could I say that: $(E[T_B | T_A \le T_B)=E(T_B + T_A)$? I most likely see it in different notations and I mess up and end up going for hard route solutions.

Comment: No - but $E[T_B\mid  T_A \le T_B]=E[T_B - T_A \mid  T_A \le T_B] + E[T_A \mid  T_A \le T_B]$ and with independent exponential distributions $E[T_B - T_A \mid  T_A \le T_B]  =E[T_B]$ while $E[T_A \mid  T_A \le T_B] = E[\min(T_A, T_B)]$